# Why signedRoute is always false on hasValidSignature in Laravel 8.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to add users only by single unique url on register.

**The problem is** that hasValidSignature() in register function always returns false, no metter if i would go directly from /register or generated url.

My RegisterController:

```
public function register(Request $request) {

        dump($request);
        dump($request->_token);
        dd($request->hasValidSignature());
        abort_unless($request->hasValidSignature(), 403, 'That link has expired or is no longer valid!');

      }
```

My index where I generate unique URL for registration:

```
public function index()
    {

        Gate::authorize('admin-level');
        $users = User::where('admin', '0')->get();
        $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'register',
            now()->addMinutes(30)
        );
        return view('backend/user/index', ['users' => $users], ['url' => $url]);
    }
```

or just generate url:

```
$url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'register',
            now()->addMinutes(30)
        );
```

Everything is done just like in documentation, that's why I'm so mad about this. What can I do to make urls good.

Its either something wrong with my hasValidSignature(which I didnt ever change)

or with my URL.

**I tried** many different methods, always with same result.

Fun fact is that it worked just after implementing. Now, it doesnt.

**I remade all auth** with `php artisan ui:auth`. Whole registration works well unless it goes with hasValidSignature.

My users have to register only from unique URL, i cannot bypass that.

Comment: Is your signed URL generated correctly? Have you checked it to see if it really includes `?signature=....`?

Comment: Example of my URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/register?expires=1630253091&signature=03d473c551a7cf839666390e19694cdf13d59610b609a42c8b06b2b72976464b ----I deleted http://

Comment: I tried using either SignedRoute and temporarySignedRoute with same result.

Comment: The URL looks legit.

Comment: Then what might be the reason, might this be something wrong with middleware?

Comment: Have you tried to validate the signature using the `signed` middleware? If not, first make sure you have the `signed` middleware defined in your `Kernel.php` under `$routeMiddleware` as such: `'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,`. Then in your web routes use `->middleware('signed');` on the register route.

Comment: After changing it to second method(from your comment) I've got error 403: Invalid signature

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are other parameters in the query included...

Therefore you must ignore them:

```
$request->hasValidSignatureWhileIgnoring(['param1', 'paramX'])
```